vmfs-fuse: can't access files on VMFS partition
I have a crashed-out VMware 5 system that I was able to preserve by copying the raw disk partitions to files several years ago. I am using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
I can mount these files using vmfs-tools but I can't actually do anything with the filesystem.
Everything I try says permission denied, even though I'm trying to use sudo to override the VMFS permissions.
sudo apt-get install vmfs-tools
vmfs-fuse sdb3 foo
cd foo
ls -l

total 40
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  700 Aug 11  2017  ISOs
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 1960 Dec 26  2018 'pfSense Router'
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 2240 Jan  8  2021 'Ubuntu 64-bit'
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  420 Jan  4  2021  vmware-update
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 2240 Jan  4  2021 'Windows 10'

cd Windows\ 10/
ls -hl

total 33G
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.3M Dec 30  2020  vmware-10.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 444K Aug 13  2017  vmware-5.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 326K Aug 14  2017  vmware-6.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.4M Dec 26  2018  vmware-7.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.2M Jan  9  2019  vmware-8.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 738K Jan 20  2019  vmware-9.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.4M Jan  4  2021  vmware.log
-rw------- 1 root root 110M Apr  2  2019 'vmx-Windows 10-4094431081-1.vswp'
-rw------- 1 root root  32G Jan  4  2021 'Windows 10-flat.vmdk'
-rw------- 1 root root 8.5K Jan  4  2021 'Windows 10.nvram'
-rw------- 1 root root  526 Jan  4  2021 'Windows 10.vmdk'
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Aug  4  2017 'Windows 10.vmsd'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3.3K Jan  4  2021 'Windows 10.vmx'
-rw------- 1 root root 3.1K Jan  4  2021 'Windows 10.vmxf'

sudo cp 'Windows 10.vmx' /home/bar/Windows10VM/
cp: cannot stat 'Windows 10.vmx': Permission denied

sudo chmod 777 'Windows 10.vmx'
chmod: cannot access 'Windows 10.vmx': Permission denied

